# SQL Query dynamic select without using IF..THEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join

I have the following db schema:

[image]

The **user** table stores the users that log in. The field "overridetemplate" is a boolean that let us know if the we get the user security template info or the user override info.

The **user_access** table associates an user to a security_template (like user role).

The **security_template** table has the security template info (example: Power User, etc)

The **security_template_exception** has all the actions with its access rights for the template (example: "insert_user" with accesstype "FullAccess", "delete_user" with accesstype "Deny")

So this way an user has a role or security template and that template has a bunch of "actions" with accesstype for that user.

Then, I have an extra table, **user_override_template**, that was created for overriding a Security Template and then you can assign indiviual actions permissions to a user without affecting a complete security template.

There are only 3 types of "accesstype: "FullAccess", "ReadOnly" and "Deny".

Right now the query that brings the security actions access is the following:

```
SELECT
                        ste.[objectid], ste.[accesstype]
                    FROM
                        [user] AS u
                        JOIN [users_access] AS ua ON u.[userid] = ua.[userid]
                        JOIN [security_template] AS st ON ua.[templateid] = st.[templateid]
                        JOIN [security_templates_exceptions] AS ste ON st.[templateid] = ste.[templateid]
                    WHERE
                        su.[userid] = @userid
```

The result of the query is something like this:

[image]

So, what I need is depeding on the field "overridetemplate" I should get the access info from "user_override_template" or "security_template_exception".

Any clue on how to do that **without using** (I want to do this in a single select):

```
IF @overridetemplate = 1
BEGIN

END
ELSE
BEGIN

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You do both joins and select which you want in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT (case when @UseSecurityTemplate = 'Y' then ste.[objectid]
             else uto.objectid
        end) as objectid
       (case when @UseSecurityTemplate = 'Y' then ste.[accesstype]
             else uto.accesstype
        end) as AccessType
FROM [user] AS u
     LEFT JOIN [users_access] AS ua ON u.[userid] = ua.[userid]
     LEFT JOIN [security_template] AS st ON ua.[templateid] = st.[templateid]
     LEFT JOIN [security_templates_exceptions] AS ste ON st.[templateid] = ste.[templateid]
     LEFT JOIN [user_override_template] AS uot ON ua.[templateid] = uot.[templateid]
WHERE su.[userid] = @userid;
```

I switched the joins to `left outer join` to prevent unwanted filtering when there are no rows around.

Comment: Its not working, its returning thousands of rows.. by the way, user_override_template has no templateid column